# Not able to Connect Git Lab and eks with Gitab agent

Tags: gitlab, amazon-eks

I am trying to connect Gitlab and Eks cluster but when I am running the command with token which I got from Gitlab I am getting below error.

```
helm repo add gitlab https://charts.gitlab.io
helm repo update
helm upgrade --install k8s-agent gitlab/gitlab-agent --namespace gitlab-agent  --create-namespace  --set image.tag=v15.1.0 --set config.token=RNH96zYYFxK(change the token) --set config.kasAddress=wss://kas-dev.corp.abc.com


E0710 14:19:37.969643   22308 memcache.go:121] couldn't get resource list for metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: an error on the server ("Internal Server Error: \"/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1?timeout=32s\": Unauthorized") has prevented the request from succeeding
```

why am I getting this error? What needs to be corrected?

Comment: The error indicates there is an application that is attempting to read metrics from the metrics server, https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server. Is the metrics server installed and does the service token grant access to the metric server? What cluster role or role is the service account token associated with?

Comment: SA has cluster admin role associated

Comment: Can you add the output of cluster role to this thread? Also, you didn't say whether the metrics server is installed.

Comment: v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io                 kube-system/metrics-server   True        596d .it is installed .